# "Extrude Faces Along Normals" works exactly as "Extrude Faces"

Tags: modeling, extrude

I have a sphere like this:

[image]

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and *Extrude Faces*, it works like:

[image]

As I'd expect of it. However, when I 'Extrude Faces Along Normals', it works like:

[image]

...and I can't tell the difference. What I expected `Extrude Faces Along Normals" to do is something like:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to achieve this effect.

**EDIT:**

[image]

I tried the 'Extrude Along Normals' tool on Tool Bar. As you can see in the picture, no luck for this one either.

Comment: Are you sure for the third image? Try to do it with the gizmo, eventually.

Comment: @lemon  tried it several times, restarted blender and create new blank files but it still doesn't work as expected. I pressed X/Y/Z while extruding but nothing happened. Strangely when I `Extrude Faces`(not along normals), X/Y/Z did what I expected. How do I "do it with the gizmo"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your pivot point is set to median.
Otherwise it won't work as expected.

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right! I wonder why there is such a difference though. What does "individual origins" mean in this context...? The origins of each individual face?